# Rename Generic Class in WebAPI

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have a Generic Envelope class that i use as the common return object for the WebAPI as follows:

```
 public class ApiEnvelope<T>
 {
     public bool Success { get; set; }
     public Error Error { get; set; }
     public Data<T> Data { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I construct a HttpResponseMessage using:

```
 Request.CreateResponse<ApiEnvelope<whatever>>(HttpStatusCude.OK, model);
```

The problem i have is that i would like the xml to be somewhat standard however the root name of the xml being returned is not standard and is coming through as ApiEnvelopeOfwhatever.

My question is how can i get the root name to be ApiEnvelope regardless of the type?

Comment: Have you checked out DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

With generic class you got no  chance, remove generic specification and set Data propert type to object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and I got a decent answer, (I know this is old but it was a good answer): [How to resolve Swashbuckle/Swagger -UI model naming issue for generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615289/how-to-resolve-swashbuckle-swagger-ui-model-naming-issue-for-generics)

Now this is only part of the solution for your question, so you should look at Github repo: [MakeGenericAgain](https://github.com/fgilde/MakeGenericAgain). Use that to "regeneric" the resultant generated code, (big heads up: if you use this on the entire code and not just names of types, you will have a mess if you have properties name things like "NumberOfUnits" because that becomes "Number").

*Sidenote:*
If you want to "level up" your skills here, then use Rolsyn's SyntaxWalker to apply the renaming, and at the same time "cleanup" duplicated classes, as many design their REST-APIs with few shared "models" so a User and a Company might hace identical "Address" -properties based on identically shaped classes but it they are defined twice your NSwag -generated code will have Address and Address2, however using Roslyn, you can identify these ande rewrite the code to give a "perfect result".