# How to resolve Swashbuckle/Swagger -UI model naming issue for generics?

Tags: c#, generics, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to clean the names of the models in the swagger ui for my webapi.

The issue is that when I define a response type on my endpoint, and that type is a generic, it gets named in such a way that if one were to use a swagger-gen tool like NSwag, the models gets the worst names, (as they're based on the swagger, I'd like to define how the model is named).

This is the response attribute:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BulkUpsertResponse<AccountingCode>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
```

This is the resultant name:
`Company.IntegrationApi.Api.Models.Responses.BulkUpsertResponse1[[Company.IntegrationApi.Api.Models.AccountingParameters.AccountingCode, Company.IntegrationApi.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`

What NSwag makes it to be:
`BulkUpsertResponse_1OfOfAccountingCodeAndApiAnd_0AndCulture_neutralAndPublicKeyToken_null`

What i'd like the name to be is:
`BulkUpsertResponse<AccountingCode>`

I've tried to find an attribute or tag to define the name, and it's not feasable to make the generics into "hard types" as it's hundreads of uses.

How can I specify the name exactly, or what work-arounds can I use to solve my issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @daveBM nope, unfortunately no. Unless I get into some really messy Regex or the actual source code of Swashbuckle, there's little one can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Swashbuckle.Swagger NuGet package.
Then in your init method use

> CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FriendlyId(true));

See example below :D

```
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;
///then in configure services..

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Version = "v1",
                        Title = "Your API",
                        Description = "Interfaces available for API",
                    });
                    c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
                    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                        Name = "Authorization",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                        Scheme = "Bearer"
                    });
                    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
                    c.CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FriendlyId(true));


                });
```

Comment: `CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FriendlyId(true));` in .NET6?